# problema con "Array to string conversion"

Tags: php

Quiero listar mensajes de muchos tickets mediante `json` pero no me deja mostrarlo ya que tengo problemas con `"Array to string conversion"` y no se del por que siendo que uso `json_decode().`

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-cluster.postcenter.io/v2/ticket/5baa469fd4a5b360ec6031a3/messages',
                     CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> TRUE,
                     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                        'Authorization: Key dfdfsdfs',
                        "cache-control: no-cache"
                    )
                    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $r=curl_exec($ch);

        if(!$r)
        {
            $mData=array( curl_error($ch) );

        } else {
            $json=json_decode($r);
            $mData=$json;
        }

        curl_close($ch);

   foreach ($mData as $nono) {
        echo $nono.PHP_EOL;

    }

?>
```

Comment: Puedes poner un var_dump($r) que supongo que son los datos que traes de la api, para asi comprobar que el formato es el correcto, recuerda editar tu pregunta y añadirlo allí

Comment: string(11751) "{"status": 200, "messages": [{"assigned_to": null, "author_name": "Sof\u00eda Trisotti Bernain", "answer_by": null, "is_private": "private", "publisher": null, "kind": "private", "created": "2018-09-27T16:17:43", "is_mention": true, "content": "                                                         obtengo solo esos datos y son muchos mas campos

Comment: @KeTeMeTo al hacer un var_dump($r) me aparece todos los datos, pero cuando quiero seleccionar un dato en especifico me aparece el error de conversion a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> string(11751) "{"status": 200, "messages": [{"assigned_to": null, "author_name": "Sof\u00eda Trisotti Bernain", "answer_by": null, "is_private": "private", "publisher": null, "kind": "private", "created": "2018-09-27T16:17:43", "is_mention": true, "content": " obtengo solo esos datos y son muchos más campos

El error se debe a que al iterar `$mData` la variable `$nono` en la segunda vuelta será el arreglo de `"messages"`, el cual, no se puede imprimir directamente haciendo `echo $nono.PHP_EOL;`

#### Solución:

Imagino que lo que buscas iterar es el arreglo de mensajes e imprimir algunos datos del mismo, para lo cual podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
//... código anterior

//
foreach ($mData->messages as $nono) {
    echo json_encode($nono).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Si necesitas acceder e imprimir algún dato puntual de cada mensaje, puedes hacerlo así:

```
//... código anterior

//
foreach ($mData->messages as $msg) {
    echo $msg->author_name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: aparece este error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`  ||  `Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown`, a partir de la lines 29 donde comienza el foreach.

Comment: Lo que busco es guardar todos los datos de mensajes en una BD y que al final son miles de mensajes.

Comment: @YerckoOrtega, primero debes intentarlo, si no lo logras, entonces crea una nueva pregunta solicitando ayuda incluyendo el código que intentaste

Comment: Utilize el foreach actualizado que me mandaste y me aparece este error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` || `Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown`

Comment: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$messages` ||  `NULL` eso aparece

Comment: Quiere decir que algo está fallando antes. ¿y `var_dump($mData)`?

Comment: tenia error en la key pero ya lo resolvi, pero cuando intento traer solo un campo de los mensajes no me lo arroja y me da estos errores:  `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object ` ||  `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach`.   intente traer author_name pero arrojo el error.

Comment: `foreach ($mData->messages->author_name as $nono) {
   echo json_encode($nono).PHP_EOL;
  }`

Comment: Gracias eso era lo que necesitaba crack. Saludos gracias por la ayuda.